# Microsoft Dynamics CRM - How to insert a new record in a entity/table

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have created an entity in Microsoft Dynamics CRM using "Settings => Customization => Customize the System" options which is available in the Dynamics CRM dashboard.

However I'm stuck out in finding a way to insert data to the entity which I've created.

I don't want to insert data through C# or SSIS (or) Bulk upload methods, and I'm just looking for a wizard/form to add/insert the data.

Can someone help?

Comment: SO is about programming, so your question is off-topic here.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen Sorry about that, However my requirement is to accomplish this not through programming and I have been looking for options other than that, since I'm new to this CRM I had to post this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to adding your entity to a section is you can use advanced find.  You can find advanced find by selecting the Filter (Funnel) Symbol at the top right of your CRM screen.

[image: CRM Title Bar]

Advanced find should open, change look for to your entity and click results.

[image]

You can then click the new button from the results screen.

[image]

Comment: Although, I figured it on my own.. This was the approach I found out to fetch the data.. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics CRM has built-in import wizard which you can access via Settings > Data Management > Imports > Import Data.

[image: data mgmt]

And it's also available from most entity views:

[image]

And [here's a link](http://crmbook.powerobjects.com/basics/data-management-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/importing-data-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/the-data-import-wizard-in-dynamics-crm/) containing more info on how to use it.

Comment: Hi Aron, Thanks for the reply!. But I don't want to go with this approach (or) the approaches listed in the link you've shared, Is there a way available in the CRM dashboard itself to achieve this (maybe a form (or) wizard) ?

Comment: OK, your use of the word "upload" threw me off. You might to remove it from your question. And +1 for Pawel's response below. Another way to create a new record is to find the entity in Advanced Find, on the default query click Results, and then New.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the question to remove that term.

Answer (score 0):

When you created your entity there were a section about where this entity should be displayed (Sales, Service, Marketing, Settings etc.). You should have checked one of this checkboxes.

After creating entity you should click `Publish all Customizations` button (which is displayed on the upper menu of the solution where you've added your entity).

Now your entity will be available through the upper menu in whichever section you've chosen (for example in Sales section). You create a record of your custom entity exactly like the other entities (Accounts, Contacts, whatever), there is no difference.